# Multiple date picker control validation (More than 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datepicker

I have 7 date pickers in a pop over and I need a validation for all.
Please check the image.
Front end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwRGN.jpg

Here survey date < packing date < export clearance date  < dispatch date  < import clearance date  < delivery date

I have got examples where there are only two date pickers are present in the view, but they are not helping in this context. Can someone help in tackling this issue in code? I need the calendar to remain disabled for all dates prior to date selected in the previous row. Also I want the calendar to skip months and show the month only where date are enabled (i.e suppose my survey date is 31 January then packing date calendar should open February month and not January)

Code:

```
@model IList<Writer.Repository.Models.MovePlanAT>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = I18N("Move Plan");
}

<div id="wrap-MovePlanAT">
    <div class="ibox" id="pnlMovePlanAT">
        <div class="ibox-title no-padding no-borders">
            <h5>@I18N("Move Plan")</h5>
            <div class="ibox-tools">
                <button type="button" class="close-link close marl-5" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("MovePlanUpdate/" + ViewData["MoveID"], "Move", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "frmMovePlanAT" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="ibox-content clearfix" id="pnlMovePlanAT">
                <div class="row">
                    @{ int i = 0; }
                    @for (i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-5">@I18N(Model[i].ActivityName)</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm datemp">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].TaskUpDatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @placeholder = @I18N(Model[i].ActivityName), @data_format = ShortDateFormatJs } })
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].TaskUpDatedOn, "", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "text-danger" }, { "data-valmsg-for", "[" + i + "].TaskUpDatedOn" } })

                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].MoveID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ShipmentModeID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ActivityScoreboardID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ShipmentModeID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ActivityName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CummulativeHrs)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].TaskDateOn)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="m-t-sm m-b-sm" />
                }
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group no-margins">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <input id="btnMovePlanSave" type="submit" value="@I18N("Save")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#pnlMovePlanAT .datemp').datetimepicker({
                format: "@ShortDateFormatDatePickerJs"
            }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                @*console.log(e.date.format("@ShortDateFormatDatePickerJs"))
                console.log($(e.target).find('input[type="date"]'))*@
                // logic to check with next datepicker in the list
            }).datetimepicker('dp.update');

            $('#btnMovePlanSave').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $('#pnl-moveplan').mask("@I18N("Loading...")");
                $('form#frmMovePlanAT').ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#wrap-MovePlanAT').html(data.Result);
                        if (data.Success) {
                            toastr.success("@I18N("Move plan saved successfully.")");
                            $('[data-target="' + $('.webui-popover.in').attr('id') + '"]').webuiPopover('hide');
                            fnReloadMoveStats();
                        }
                        $('#pnl-moveplan').unmask();
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#pnl-moveplan').unmask();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciable!